# Adding a parity drive to a RAID-Z1 array

Tags: raid, zfs, freenas, raid-z

Can I create an array as a RAID-Z1 and then later add another pairity drive to make it into a RAID-Z2?

I’ve got 4TB of data on a drive I’d like to add into an array that I’m building out of fresh drives, and it’d be nice to not have to move that data elsewhere as I build out my FreeNAS box.

Comment: I'm frankly not sure if it's a duplicate or not, but you definitely want to read [Growing a ZFS pool from populated ext4 disks](http://superuser.com/a/768752/53590) and [How many drives do I need for ZFS RAID-Z2?](http://superuser.com/a/1058545/53590). Both of those focus on Linux, while FreeNAS is based on FreeBSD, but should be of interest anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Since posting this, I actually got my question answered on IRC, so I'll close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually asked this in the #freenas IRC channel, and they were able to answer my question.

To answer my own question: no, you cannot add an additional drive to a RAID-Z1 array to make it into a RAID-*Z2* array. The nor can you add additional drives to scale the array horizontally. The geometry of the array is set when you first build it.

You *can* however, grow the capacity *vertically* by adding larger drives one by one. So, I could grow my 6x4TB RAID-Z2 array by replacing each drive with an 8TB drive, and allowing it to rebuild each time I swap out a drive. The details of that are beyond me though.

They also *strongly* recommened against setting up a RAID-Z1 array. Always use Z2 or better to avoid losing the whole array if you lose two drives.

Comment: See some additional suggestions in a similar case here: http://serverfault.com/questions/778617/will-zfs-automatically-switch-to-fault-tolerant-when-i-add-a-third-drive/778647#778647 Also, expanding with bigger drives is simple if your pool has set `autoexpand=on` (expands to bigger disks automatically) and `autoreplace=on` (uses new disks in same slot automatically).